# Issue Regarding Garbage Collection/Auto delete on MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, garbage-collection

I am writing a few tables for a MySQL database, and within those tables I have entries that I only need for a few weeks.

For example:

```
create table LoginAttempts (
ReferenceId int unsigned auto_increment not null,
UserId smallint unsigned not null,
EventTime timestamp not null...)
```

Now I have no need to keep records of user login attempts forever, so I plan on deleting them after, say, 30 days. Obviously I need this operation to happen automatically.  My original thought was to add a trigger to this table that would run each time an entry is made to the table. Basically, it would simply compare each row's timestamp to the current timestamp - if it is over 30 days old, that row would be deleted.

However, my concern is possible performance impact. This method, at least to me, seems inefficient. There ought to be a better way. So, how can I implement what I want to do in a better manner - if there is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cron job or **[MySql events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)** for that.

If you go with mysql events you create an event like this

```sql
CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
   DELETE 
     FROM LoginAttempts 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(EventTime)) > 30;
```

Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to check if event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
Use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
More on configuring event scheduler [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was not familiar with MySQL events.